# Class::$template_dir_path=get_template_directory();

Tags: functions, theme-development

I have seen in some template files the following class line:

```
Class::$template_dir_path=get_template_directory();
```

What does this mean? Why is it used? What are the benefits?

Answer (score 0):

`get_template_directory` is a helper function to be used in themes. it returns the complete path of theme directory.

advantage?

```
require_once get_template_directory().'some-function.php';
```

got it?

Comment: my question was why a static call was added in front. Like SAMPLE::get_template_directory. I understand that static here automatically called without instantiation. But how could it help better than the normal call method with new object instantiation.

Comment: new object instantiation will maybe affect other methods and values with in that class. so just loading it as static will simply get the value of called property or method. static methods inl php is same as normal php functions